# FOR XML PATH. Nesting with embedded select statement

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, for-xml-path

When using the following SQL From a single temp Table.

```
Select  DataType as '@Datatype',
 (Select
 'Order' as [Property/@name],
 Order1 as Property,
 null,
  'ExtCode' as [Property/@name],
 ExtCode as Property,
 null
 from #TempLine
 for xml path('Properties'), type
 )
 from #TempLine
 Group by DataType
 for xml path('Object'), root('Objects')
```

I am getting the following XML

```
 <Objects>
      <Object Datatype="ItemInfo">
        <Properties>
          <Property name="Order">150825CREC004</Property>
          <Property name="ExtCode">150825CREC004#ISSMS</Property>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
          <Property name="Order">150825CREC004</Property>
          <Property name="ExtCode">150825CREC004#IMF</Property>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
          <Property name="Order">150825CREC004</Property>
          <Property name="ExtCode">150825CREC004#ILZF</Property>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
          <Property name="Order">150825CREC004</Property>
          <Property name="ExtCode">150825CREC004#L5898.5W</Property>
        </Properties>
      </Object>
    </Objects>
```

I Need to return the following XML with Object surrounding Properties.

```
 <Objects>
      <Object Datatype="ItemInfo">
        <Properties>
          <Property name="Order">150825CREC004</Property>
          <Property name="ExtCode">150825CREC004#ISSMS</Property>
        </Properties>
      </Object>
      <Object Datatype="ItemInfo">
        <Properties>
          <Property name="Order">150825CREC004</Property>
          <Property name="ExtCode">150825CREC004#IMF</Property>
        </Properties>
      </Object>
      <Object Datatype="ItemInfo">
        <Properties>
          <Property name="Order">150825CREC004</Property>
          <Property name="ExtCode">150825CREC004#ILZF</Property>
        </Properties>
      </Object>
      <Object Datatype="ItemInfo">
        <Properties>
          <Property name="Order">150825CREC004</Property>
          <Property name="ExtCode">150825CREC004#L5898.5W</Property>
        </Properties>
      </Object>
    </Objects>
```

I thought I could do it with embedded select but its not working out. I need to be able to have the object surround each of the properties and not the whole block.

Comment: Realized had to change SQL. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Found answer to my question. Thank you for your time

[Nesting example that worked for me.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770689/sql-server-nesting-elements-with-for-xml-path